# Print quality problems

Tags: printing, printer

I have a HP LaserJet 500 color M551 that is printing magenta on every page. 
I have tried the normal fixes, such as replacing the toner, replacing the waste toner tray, cleaning the drum, cleaning the rollers, cleaning the fusser.

I have also tried Calibration, and printer cleaning files. 
 the problem remains. There are roller marks, and initially, I thought ok, clean the rollers. but they are dirty again, every time, with magenta. So then I replaced the fusser. But the dang printer still sending out magenta pages.

So I thought I would be clever, I printed a solid page of magenta. 
the margins, still had the magenta lines, but the place the place magenta was printed is clear. 
 it still prints magenta.  why?

[Heres pictures of whats happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbJYw.jpg)

Comment: Sorry I hope you don't mind me laughing, but this seems too funny. Anyways, it's a laser printer? Have you tried swapping the toner cartridges in the printer, say put the Cyan in the place of the Magenta? Some printers are smart to detect this, but some are not.

Comment: Ok I tried it, It was detected, but I swapped the chips on the cartridges, and still got the same problem. Im going to write to the toner manufacturer and request a product that isnt defective.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did it sill print magenta or the swapped colour?

Comment: It still printed magenta

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the cartridges. I have about 4 bad ones, evidently (despite being brand new) I have contacted the OEM of the cartridges, and will be getting replacements. the 5th cartridge I tried ended up working and solving the problem.

when I started flipping the chips and still had the same problem I realized it must be the cartridge. So that comment was helpful @dark_st3alth